# segfault when writing into data segment, even though sufficient space allocated with brk()

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

My idea is to call brk() with an argument of 0 to get the current end of the data segment. Then add the amount of bytes I want to allocate to that, and call brk again with my new size. I'm running this with nasm on 32 bit Linux using the emulator here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_assembly_online.php

After that I begin writing to the data segment, starting from the msg variable in the data segment. Here's my code:

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:                     

    mov eax, 45     ;45 = brk() syscall number
    mov ebx, 0      ; invalid argument for brk

    int 0x80        ;eax now contains break

    mov esi, eax    ;save data segment break
    mov eax, 45
    add ebx, esi
    add ebx, 30000
    int 0x80        ; add 30,000 bytes to break
    mov edx, msg    ;load an address in the data section
    jmp smash_heap

exit:
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80

smash_heap:
    mov edi, 10000
loop:
    cmp edi, 0
    je exit
    ;write to data segment
    inc edx
    mov word [edx], 'c'
    dec edi
    jmp loop

section .data

msg db  'Hello, world!',0xa ;get an address in the data segment
```

I get a segmentation fault! Even though I've allocated tens of thousands of bytes more than should be necessary. Could anyone give me some pointers on why this might be crashing? I'm pretty new to assembly but everything I've learned about the data segment says this should work. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone who find this: the problem is that I started writing from msg; I should have started writing at the beginning of the heap returned by brk the first time. This article explains: https://seisvelas.github.io/journal/asm-heap/